# AngularJS: Which is better way to pass parameter to Modal Controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angular-ui-modal

I have seen two ways of passing the parameters to the `AngularJS` `Modal`, one via `resolve` binding and another via `scope` binding. I was wondering if one is better than the other and why?

**Resolve Binding**

```
$modal.open({

      templateUrl: 'partials.html',
      controller: 'MyCtrl',
      resolve: {
         someData: function(){
             return 'Some Data';
         }
      }
})
```

---

```
.controller('MyCtrl',function(someData){

     console.log(someData); // prints Some Data
})
```

**Scope Binding**

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new();
scope.someData = 'Some Data';

$modal.open({

      templateUrl: 'partials.html',
      controller: 'MyCtrl',
      scope: scope
})
```

---

```
.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){

     console.log($scope.someData); // prints Some Data
})
```

Comment: Same thing in your case

Answer (score 2):

**Resolve** is not considered as **binding** in this case.
When `$modal.open` it pass the value to the controller through resolve. Which means if you change the value in the parent controller, modal won't update unless it's re-initialize.
However, You can pass in promises in resolve, which means if you are waiting for data coming back from server, using resolve can prevent modal loads before data come back.

```
resolve: {
  someData: function() {
    return $http.get('someurl');
  }
}
```

Pros & Cons

> - Run code asynchronously
> - Slower (if use promise)
> - Does not bind with parent scope value

---

**Scope binding** will allow you to have one-way binding data, whenever the data in the parent scope update, the value in the modal can update it's value simultaneously.

Pros & Cons

> - Faster
> - Binding with parent scope value
> - Might have scope pollution if you alter value in modal controller